# Как сделать ограниченную всплывающую клавиатуру

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

**Доброго времени коллеги**, есть такой **вопрос**. 
Как можно сделать, чтобы при нажатии на текстовом поле, всплывала клавиатура только с буквами конкретного порядка.

Например: Мне в клавиатуре не нужны буквы **ы, ч, ъ, ь**. Мне нужно их скрыть. Не совсем понимаю как это организовать.

Буду весьма признателен за ответ.

Comment: Вам подходит использование кастомной клавиатуры? Где Вы сами укажете какиме символы должны быть

Answer (score 1):

Надо делать кастомную клавиатуру. Или организовать фильтрование введенных символов на лету.